# How do I hide default CommandMenu in SwiftUI on macOS?

Tags: swiftui, macos-big-sur

I'm (attempting) switching over my AppDelegate macOS app to the SwiftUI lifecycle - but can't seem to find out how to handle the CommandMenu. I just want to delete these default menu items (Fie, Edit, View, etc...). In the past, I would just delete them from the Storyboard - but I'm not using a storyboard here. Is there a way to delete these items in SwiftUI?

The items I want to delete:

[image: The items I want to delete]

I know how to add new items via:

```
.commands {
  MyAppMenus()
}
```

But that just adds them inline with the existing menu items.

Answer (score 5):

swiftUI -- override AppDelegate with your custom:

```
@main
struct PixieApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
///........
}
```

code of appDelegate:

```
final class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationWillUpdate(_ notification: Notification) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let menu = NSApplication.shared.mainMenu {
                menu.items.removeFirst{ $0.title == "Edit" }
                menu.items.removeFirst{ $0.title == "File" }
                menu.items.removeFirst{ $0.title == "Window" }
                menu.items.removeFirst{ $0.title == "View" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: This worked for me. I don't seem to have a problem with SwiftUI adding menu items back like the other commenter mentions, so I was able to stick this under `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. Note: `applicationWillUpdate` is called a *lot*, forever.

Comment: applicationDidFinishLaunching works until first refresh of menu ,thats why better applicationWillUpdate - to update once more when this menu will be refreshed.

Answer (score 2):

Until SwiftUI adds more support for adjusting menus, I think you have to worry about SwiftUI reseting the `NSApp.mainMenu` whenever it updates a `window.body`. I haven't tried every method for adjusting the `mainMenu`, but of the methods I tried, the flaw was that SwiftUI seems to have no check for whether it last set `NSApp.mainMenu` or if something else did.

So however you are managing the menu, update it after SwiftUI has.

Use KVO and watch the NSApp for changes on .mainMenu. Then make your changes with a xib, or reseting the whole thing, or editing SwiftUI's menus.

Example:

```swift
@objc
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    var token: NSKeyValueObservation?
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        
        // Adjust a menu initially
        if let m = NSApp.mainMenu?.item(withTitle: "Edit") {
            NSApp.mainMenu?.removeItem(m)
        }

        // Must refresh after every time SwiftUI re adds
        token = NSApp.observe(\.mainMenu, options: .new) { (app, change) in
            // Refresh your changes
            guard let menu = app.mainMenu?.item(withTitle: "Edit") else { return }
            app.mainMenu?.removeItem(menu)
        }
    }
}

struct MarblesApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some View { 
        //... 
    }
}
```

This seems to work in Xcode 13.4.1 with Swift 5 targeting macOS 12.3.

Hopefully Apple adds greater control soon. It seems Catalyst has other options. Or you can create a traditional AppKit app and insert the SwiftUI views into it.

Comment: This seems to work reliably. I’m having trouble adapting the solution to remove the File > Share menu item that comes with a SwiftUI document-based app. SwiftUI doesn’t provide a `CommandGroupPlacement` for the Share command, so I can’t remove it the official way. I can get the File menu with `let fileMenu = items.first { $0.title == "File" }` and the share menu command with `fileMenu?.submenu?.items.first {$0.title == "Share"}`. But I can't figure out how to use the KVO observer to detect when SwiftUI re-adds the Share command.

Comment: I couldn't come up with a simple solution. Maybe you can use `NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSMenu.didAddItemNotification, object: nil)` instead of KVO and check each time if it is the item you want to remove (e.g. the "Share"). And then remove it when it is. I have found messing with the menus too cumbersome at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove command menu items through the AppDelegate file:

```swift
override func buildMenu(with builder: UIMenuBuilder) {
    super.buildMenu(with: builder)
    builder.remove(menu: .services)
    builder.remove(menu: .format)
    builder.remove(menu: .toolbar)
}
```

This thread on the Apple Developer forum might help as well: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/649096

Comment: That would work if I'm using Catalyst but I'm not - UIMenuBuilder isn't available on macOS.

Comment: @JoeBayLD Oh, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Working off of the above, but using NotificationCenter vs KVO.

```
final class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        let unwantedMenus = ["File", "Edit"]
        
        let removeMenus = {
            unwantedMenus.forEach {
                guard let menu = NSApp.mainMenu?.item(withTitle: $0) else { return }
                NSApp.mainMenu?.removeItem(menu)
            }
        }

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            forName: NSMenu.didAddItemNotification,
            object: nil,
            queue: .main
        ) { _ in
            // Must refresh after every time SwiftUI re adds
            removeMenus()
        }

        removeMenus()
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
CommandGroup(replacing: CommandGroupPlacement.appVisibility, addition: {})
```

Comment: Please can you develop you answer?

Comment: Can you add some explanation why/how this solves the OP's question.