# How do I hide default CommandMenu entries in SwiftUI on macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am trying to delete the default menu items of my SwiftUI App, like described in this question by JoeBayLD ([How do I hide default CommandMenu in SwiftUI on macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65209295/how-do-i-hide-default-commandmenu-in-swiftui-on-macos))

None of the answers there seem to work and neither did I find another solution.
Any idea how to delete the default items?

[image: Screenshot of menu bar]

Comment: Read [this article](https://troz.net/post/2021/swiftui_mac_menus/) and see if it helps you

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunally it doesn't solve my Problem :/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I hide default CommandMenu in SwiftUI on macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65209295/how-do-i-hide-default-commandmenu-in-swiftui-on-macos)

Answer (score 3):

I recently went through this and was unable to remove the sections (File, Edit, View), so I settled with removing some of the items that didn't apply to my app.

This is what I ended up with. It doesn't include `.newItem` because I replaced it, but if you don't need it I would suggest adding it, otherwise users can create more windows of your app.

```
struct EmptyCommands: Commands {
    var body: some Commands {
        CommandGroup(replacing: .saveItem) {
            EmptyView()
        }
        CommandGroup(replacing: .printItem) {
            EmptyView()
        }
        CommandGroup(replacing: .undoRedo) {
            EmptyView()
        }
        CommandGroup(replacing: .pasteboard) {
            EmptyView()
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, even if you remove all the items in a group, the group stays, even if empty.

There's probably a way of doing this using AppKit, but I didn't dig deeper because my solution was good enough for me.

Comment: Thank you! Kinda sad that Apple doesn't include an easy way of removing the menu items completly in SwiftUI.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all of the default menu items you can use the
.commandsRemoved() modifier on your WindowGroup