# Selectively Removing Default Menu Bar Menus (like File, Edit, and View) in macOS App Using SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui, menu, menubar

Is there a `SwiftUI` idiomatic way to selectively remove the defualt (`File`, `Edit`, and `View`) menus from the menu bar in a macOS app, while keeping other menus like the AppName menu intact? The app I’m building is a simple utility, so `Edit` and `View` menus are not relevant in this context.

I’m aware of the new [`.commandsRemoved()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scene/commandsremoved()), available since macOS 13, but that apparently removes all menus.

I’m looking for a pure `SwiftUI` solution. Any guidance and help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65209295/how-do-i-hide-default-commandmenu-in-swiftui-on-macos/70553784#70553784

Comment: @jnpdx No. The solution is quite inelegant since my app is localized in numerous languages. I would need to find the menu names for each language and then match the strings. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @jnpdx `UIMenuBuilder` isn’t available on macOS. I’m not using Mac Catalyst.

Comment: To anyone interested, please read: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/740591?answerId=770477022#770477022

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing all commands using `.commandsRemoved()`,
then adding back only the ones you want.
You can also show/hide the particular `command` using a condition.

```
 @main
 struct TestMacApp: App {
     @State var showView = false
     
     var body: some Scene {
         WindowGroup {
             ContentView()
         }
         .commandsRemoved()
         .commandsReplaced {
             CommandGroup(replacing: .help, addition: {})
             if showView { CommandGroup(replacing: .textEditing, addition: {}) }
             // ...
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that was one of the first things I tried. However, this method does not work. `AppName`menu remains empty after you bring back `.appInfo`, `.appVisibility`, `.appTermination`, etc.