# Unremovable Empty “View” Menu Bar Container

Tags: macos, swiftui, menu, menubar

In an app written in pure `SwiftUI`, which doesn’t use tab bar, toolbar, or sidebar, with full-screen mode disabled, the system default `View` top-level menu bar container remains visible even though it’s completely empty.

If the `View` menu is empty, it should not be visible in the menu bar.

```
// App does not use sidebar nor toolbar

// Disable automatic window tabbing
NSWindow.allowsAutomaticWindowTabbing = false

// Disable zoom button
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSApplication.willUpdateNotification), perform: { _ in
    if let window = NSApplication.shared.mainWindow {
        window.standardWindowButton(.zoomButton)?.isEnabled = false
    }
})

// Disable full-screen mode
.windowResizability(.contentSize)

// “View” menu in menu bar should now be empty
```

How can I disable or hide `View` menu using only `SwiftUI`?

*Click to view the gif:*

[image: Empty View menu still visible]

Comment: Do you want to remove all the menu items (including "File", "Edit" etc), or just remove "View"?

Comment: @Sweeper In this case, I just want ‘View’ menu to disappear when it’s empty. For ‘File’, ‘Edit’, etc. see https://stackoverflow.com/q/77390451/7840155.